# Teamviewer 11, Ubuntu 15.10, Three monitors on Nvidia drivers - black screen

Tags: teamviewer

I'm running Teamviewer 11 on Ubuntu 15.10, running three monitors on the Nvidia drivers. I primarily use Teamviewer to connect to my desktop system from my android phone, but when I connect to this machine, I can see my desktop for a few seconds, but as soon as I try to click anything, the entire screen goes black on the device. Sitting at the desktop, I can see the mouse moving around, but "clicks" don't seem to be sent, and, of course, I don't intend to use this while sitting in front of the montors. Has anyone run across this, and is there a fix? Alternately, can someone suggest an alternate method (or a good guide TO an alternate method,) that a relative linux noob would be able to follow, for a remote desktop solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah; found the issue and fixed it. Apparantly, my Nvidia settings wasn't recognizing my SLI, and was forcing me to use Xinerama and a single X Screen on each monitor, instead of a single X screen spread across three monitors, and apparantly this was causing issues (Not only this issue, but also some issues I was seeing with Google chrome.)
Modifying my X config file manually to be very similar to https://www.martineve.com/2014/04/15/enabling-a-triple-head-3-monitor-setup-on-linux-mint-16-petra-with-two-nvidia-cards/ has corrected everything.